# Convert rotation from sign switching to continuous in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

*Plane* is simply rotating on Z axis around origin from 0 deg to infinity (linear interpolation), AN extracts this rotation from polygon. Extracted motion looks fine but it isn't calculated as cumulated/continuous value. Every 180 degrees it is switching sign from `+` to `-`.

Look at **Z** value here:

[image]

Can this rotation be recalculated to match input motion? I was planning to change some values inside material in [0-1] range using growing angle, but unable to do it with current behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This signed representation is called a *Directed Angle*. To convert that to a non-directed angle, simply add $2\pi$ if the result is negative as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

This is assuming you angles are in radians, if they are in degrees, you should be adding 360 instead.

Comment: Good to know it has a proper name. So, to go beyond 360 I should store every negative appearance and add another 360? Or is there anything easier than that?

Comment: @SergeL Take the modulo with the maximum range, $\pi$ or $2\pi$ depending on when you perform the modulo.